Table disappearing if inputting special characters
I am using reactable with custom filtering/searching methods and regular expression patterns, and special functions to collapse rows if they are identical (to avoid repetition of the same rows, which can occur in my database). See a reproducible example below:
library(reactable)
library(htmltools)

customsearch <-  JS('
function(rows, columnIds, filterValue) {
    let arrFilterValues = filterValue.split(" ");

    return rows.filter(function(row) {
        return arrFilterValues.map(function(e) {
            return columnIds.some(function(columnId) {
                return new RegExp(e,"i").test(row.values[columnId])
            });
        }).every(v => v === true);
    });
}')

customfilter <- JS('function(rows, columnId, filterValue) {
    let arrFilterValues = filterValue.split(" ");

    return rows.filter(function(row) {
        return arrFilterValues.map(function(e) {
                return new RegExp(e,"i").test(row.values[columnId])
        }).every(v => v === true);
    });
}')


reactable(iris,filterable=TRUE,searchable=TRUE,static=TRUE, rowStyle=JS("function(rowInfo, state) {
    const firstSorted = state.sorted[0]
    if (!firstSorted || firstSorted.id === 'Petal.Length') {
      const prevRow = state.pageRows[rowInfo.viewIndex - 1]
      if (prevRow && rowInfo.values['Petal.Length'] === prevRow['Petal.Length']) {
        return { visibility: 'collapse' }
      }
    }
  }"), searchMethod = customsearch, defaultColDef=colDef(filterMethod=customfilter, html=TRUE))

The problem is that, if I input some characters in the search box, the table disappear and the only way to make it appear again is to refresh the page: I can put numbers or text in the search box, but as soon as I input "\" (as well as other special characters I guess, such as "*") the table disappears. This also occur if I input a string which is not found in the table.
Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Is your goal to search for values like "\" or "*" or just to prevent the crash if somebody does? And what do you mean by This also occur if I input a string which is not found in the table.? It works for me in this case, the result set then has zero rows.

@Jan - I actually want to prevent the crash if somebody does.
Regarding the zero rows case - it may works in the example that I link, but it doesn’t with the custom filter function that I have added after editing my question - in that case, the table disappear.
On a general note I would like to understand how to prevent the table to “crash” if one input an “unpermitted” character/string in the search box, or in other words how to write “safe” custom filter functions to avoid table crash.

Could you please add a minimal, reproducible example for the zero rows case with your custom filter function? I just looked at my old answer and cannot replicate a crash if there are zero rows found.

@Jan thanks for your help - I have added a reproducible example and gave some more context to make my error reproducible.

Thanks, now I see the problems and can reproduce them. Your question currently needs one more reopen vote to get re-opened.

@Jan I think this one will not be reopened - I have posted another one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78811152/reactable-disappearing-with-custom-filter-search-function-if-inputting-special-c. When I get an answer I will delete this one.

This is not how SO works. Your new question is a duplicate to this one. Also you can't delete this question because it has an upvoted answer.

@Jan I understand, I am sorry for that. I have deleted the other question.

Thanks, your question is now reopened. Maybe one point: I don't understand your rowStyle function. In the example you have the iris dataset and in the JS you say something about schools and e.g. filter for Journal. What is the purpose here and can you provide an example which is more clear? I see the problem inside the JS but need to know what you want to have in order to apply a suitable change.

@Jan Ahh you're right - sorry for that. To make a reproducible example I forgot to adapt my code to the iris dataset. Please find new code updated - in the updated reproducible example, basically the rowStyle function is intended to "collapse" (or to say better, "hide") any row that have the same value for Petal.Length. This is an intended behavior as in my dataset I may have very similar rows and I want to show only the first occurrence, while keeping all filterables and searchable (hope this makes sense).

The table disappears if the filtered result set has zero rows because in the  rowStyle function you have a rowInfo.viewIndex and this is undefined if the filtered table has zero rows (in particular, rowInfo is undefined in this case). I added an extra condition inside the function which checks for this case, this should avoid the crash.
Concerning the crash if the user inputs a special character the problem is that that in this case no regex for the search can be constructed. Below I implemented a solution where in such a situation I remove the last character from the filter value and return this result set (i.e., the last filtered result set is kept). There are also other possibilities, e.g. returning an empty table.
library(reactable)
library(htmltools)

customsearch <-  JS('
function(rows, columnIds, filterValue) {
    let arrFilterValues = filterValue.split(" ");
      return rows.filter(function(row) {
          return arrFilterValues.map(function(e) {
              return columnIds.some(function(columnId) {
                  try {
                      return new RegExp(e,"i").test(row.values[columnId]);
                  } catch (err) {
                      return new RegExp(e.slice(0, -1), "i").test(row.values[columnId]);;
                  }
              });
          }).every(v => v === true);
      });
}')

customfilter <- JS('function(rows, columnId, filterValue) {
    let arrFilterValues = filterValue.split(" ");

    return rows.filter(function(row) {
        return arrFilterValues.map(function(e) {
            try {
                return new RegExp(e,"i").test(row.values[columnId]);
            } catch (err) {
                return new RegExp(e.slice(0, -1), "i").test(row.values[columnId]);;
            }
        }).every(v => v === true);
    });
}')

reactable(iris,filterable=TRUE,searchable=TRUE,static=TRUE, rowStyle=JS("function(rowInfo, state) {
    const firstSorted = state.sorted[0]
    if ((!firstSorted || firstSorted.id === 'Petal.Length') && (rowInfo !== undefined)) {
      const prevRow = state.pageRows[rowInfo.viewIndex - 1]
      if (prevRow && rowInfo.values['Petal.Length'] === prevRow['Petal.Length']) {
        return { visibility: 'collapse' }
      }
    }
  }"), searchMethod = customsearch, defaultColDef=colDef(filterMethod=customfilter, html=TRUE))


Woa, that's brilliant! Thanks also for explaining what you've done.

You could handle error if the proposed regex (a single \) is invalid, and return the whole table in that case ? I'm not a daily javascript user, more python/R and I also prefer to avoid regex as much as possible, so I may be missing other better approaches but this appears to work on basic test.
replace the JS("") part with
"function(rows, columnId, filterValue) {
                          try {
          const pattern = new RegExp(filterValue, 'i');
          return rows.filter(function(row) {
            return pattern.test(row.values[columnId]);
          });
        } catch (e) {
          // If regex creation fails, return all rows
          return rows;
        }
      }"


Thanks - but I understood that more details are needed otherwise this will not be clear. I will edit my question.
